# Nested use of primefaces datalist and fieldset

Tags: primefaces

Is it possible to use primefaces datalist and fieldset elements in a nested way. My application needs to look something like this:

```
<p:fieldset>
    <p:dataList>
        <p:fieldset>
            <p:datalist>

            </p:datalist>
        </p:fieldset> 
    </p:dataList>
</p:fieldset>
```

I've tried it as mentioned above but I always get the following error:

*javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /WEB-INF/flows/mainapp/wholesaleInfo.xhtml @106,105  Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: datalist*

The datalist mentioned in the error message is of course the inner one... Any ideas how I could make that work? thanks Nikolaus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `dataList` camelCase instead of `datalist`, in the inner one. This should make the error go away. However I am unsure if dataLists can be nested. If it's just for layout - display purpose, you may have a look at `p:layout`

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to use primefaces components only. I'm sure that it's possible to nest datalists because I have already done this in another page. In the above mentioned example there seems to be a problem with the combination of fieldsets and datalists. I've already tried to change the first datalist against a <ui:repeat> but the error stays the same. Any other suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion was pointing to Primefaces components. Have you tried to solve the above mentioned error by using p:dataList instead of p:datalist? The second suggestion was referring to PrimeFaces' p:layout

Comment: ah, ok... sorry, than I understood you wrong. I was not aware of a difference between dataList and datalist. I#M going to try that immediately. thx

Comment: Thank you very much! As you suspected I wrote datalist with lower case capitals but it has to be dataList. thx